# Microsoft Graph DateTimeTimeZone to LocaldateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, graph, microsoft-graph-api

When I get a date (of event or task) from Graph API it is saved in an instance of DateTimeTimeZone class. This object is composed by 2 properties ( datetime and timezone ) that are strings, and rapresent a UTC date. Is there a way to convert this "date" to local DateTime?

Comment: What `DateTimeTimeZone` class seems like? Can you please create a [MCVE]? Is it _really_ hard to understand as such.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/datetimetimezone
It's a object that store a DateTime value and a TimeZone as two separate strings. Its is the return format of the graph API. For example:

{dateTime: "2018-02-14T08:30:00.0000000", timeZone: "UTC"}

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 11):

`DateTimeTimeZone` provides extension methods that take Datetime and timezone string, You can check by going into the definition of the class [DateTimeTimeZoneExtensions](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/pull/483/files#diff-a8201fcfe34ff4af92649068907f4c5e)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a workable alternative for converting to LocalDateTime or Date that's not all together advisable, you could do the following in Java (example based on `Event event`)

DateTimeTimeZone to LocalDateTime:

```
SimpleDateFormat graphDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.0000000'");
// set preferable timezone
graphDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
// set preferable zoneID
ZoneId timeZoneID = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels");

LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(graphDateFormat.parse(event.start.dateTime).toInstant(), timeZoneID);
```

DateTimeTimeZone to Date:

```
Date startDate = Date.from(Instant.parse(graphCalendarEvent.start.dateTime.substring(0, 20) + "Z"));
```

Conversion from LocalDateTime to DateTimeTimeZone:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeTimeZone dateTimeTimeZone = new DateTimeTimeZone();
dateTimeTimeZone.dateTime = localDateTime.toString();
// set preferable timezone
dateTimeTimeZone.timeZone = "W. Europe Standard Time";
```

Remember people, just because it *could* be put to production, that doesn't mean it *should*!

Comment: I am certain that it can be done without the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class. The modern `DateTimeFormatter` should be a better alternative.